# How to add a new line to textAngular WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textangular

I want to add a new line to textAngular WYSIWYG editor.

I'm using \n, but its not working

```
<text-angular ng-model="htmlContent" name="demo-editor" placeholder="sample text \n testttt"></text-angular>
```

[image]

Or

```
<text-angular ng-model="htmlContent" name="demo-editor" placeholder="sample text <br/> testttt"></text-angular>
```

[image]

Comment: @PankajParkar if you use <br/> the the show the html tag as text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to add this html class to your css

```
.placeholder-text::before {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Then you can set the text with '\a'.

```
<text-angular ng-model="htmlContent" name="demo-editor" placeholder="sample text \a testttt"></text-angular>
```

[image]